# Histogram rebinning in Matlab 2020a, when I don't have a Matlab histogram object

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have two vectors that describe a histogram: bin values/labels and bin count.
I'd like to import those into a Matlab histogram object so that I can change parameters more easily, such as the number of bins.
Here is a simplification what I have:
Center bin values:

```
BinValues(1:21) = [-10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
```

and count values per bin

```
CountValues(1:21) = [ 16 12 3 21 7 8 2 6 0 3 4 6 1 8 3 25 16 5 7 10 16];
```

My actual histogram has 800000 bins, and I want to vary the number of bins.

In my simplified example above, it would be something like reducing the bins from 21 to 15 or 21 to 11.

What I have can be graphed as a simple bar graph.

```
 bar(BinValues,CountValues);
```

But, if I want to experiment with different numbers of bins, I think it would be best to use the histogram function/object in Matlab, but I'm not sure how I do this from what I have.

OK Update:

I tried this:

```
 h=histogram('BinEdges',[-10.5:10.5] , 'BinCounts', CountValues);
```

Now I have a nice histogram, but if I use fewerbins(h), I get an error saying I can't do that while BinCountsMode is in "manual". If I modify it to be in "auto" mode, then my original histogram disappears.

The brute force solution would be to generate a huge array with repeated values as dictated by binCount values, but that seems like a dumb way to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you intend to rebin the data?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to rebin manually.

Comment: Probably not the method you want but if the bins have equal intervals (bin edges have equal separation) then you could `reshape()` the `CountValues` and take the `sum()` along the second dimension. The factor to `reshape()` by would be almost like a decimation factor. Sorry for the manual kinda approach. Only caveat is the factor need to be a factor of 800000.

Comment: @MichaelTr7, yes I've done that. Just seems to be too crude. I supposed I could write a function, but heck, it's 2020, almost 2021. Somebody must have done this before (many years ago I would have hoped), and I hoping one of those somebodies worked for Mathworks.

Comment: I agree that it's a pretty crude. Yeah, I looked for a Mathworks developed solution as well without luck.

Comment: The Matlab support staff say "no go" also. If I worked at MathWorks, I'd target that feature enhancement for the "histogram" object. Looks like I should just sum the counts of the old bins that go into each new bin.

Comment: No way actually, that's quite surprising. I guess they assume reconstruction of pseudo data using the bins and counts then taking a new histogram would be feasible but with large amounts of samples like the 800,000 that's quite a long task.

Comment: They want me to save all data points. It is worse that 800,000 as those are just the number of bins. Each will have count values in the 1000s. They say it sounds like a big data problem and direct me towards tall arrays. Manually rebinning now seems like the simplest choice. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/tall-data-visualization.html